# Are compositions of functions from compact function spaces compact?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, metric-spaces, compactness, complete-spaces

Let $X\subset \mathbb{R}^d$ and $A\subset \mathbb{R}$ be a compact sets, where $C_B(X)$ and $C_B(A)$ denote the space of continuous and bounded real-valued functions $X\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ and $A\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ respectively. Define $\mathcal{F}\subset C_B(A)$, and $\mathcal{G}\subset C(X)$ to be compact sets with respect to the metric induced by the norm $||f||_\infty =\sup_{x\in X}|f(x)|$. Then define $\mathcal{H} := \{h=f\circ g: f\in \mathcal{F}, g\in\mathcal{G}\}$.

**QUESTION:** Is the metric space $(\mathcal{H}, ||\cdot||_\infty)$ complete (Banach)? If so is it compact?

I know Arzela-Ascoli implies subsets of $C_B(X)$ are compact if and only if they are complete sets of uniformly equicontinuous and bounded functions, but I'm struggling to show that $\mathcal{H}$ is complete.

Comment: as you defined it $\mathcal H$ is a subset of $\mathbb R$. Is that what you want?

Comment: No it is not thank you for catching that. I believe it should be fixed now so $\mathcal{H}$ is a set of functions.

Comment: If $g$ takes values in $R$ and $f$ is defined on a subset of $R^d$, how can you compose f and g?

Comment: Sorry my mistake. It's fixed now.

Comment: The norm $||\cdot||_\infty$ is not well defined on the whole of $C(\mathbb R)$.

Comment: @WarlockofFiretopMountain it's not a norm on $C(X)$ but it still induces a topology there.

Comment: @Jakobian but it's not even Hausdorff, is that really what OP wants?

Comment: Thanks for catching that. I forgot to make f a function of a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}$. The norm $||\cdot||_\infty$ should be well defined now.

Comment: The composition is not well defined now, because $g\in \mathcal G$ need not have image contained in $A$.

Also, why $\mathcal H$ should be a Banach space? It does not even have a natural vector space structure in general.